# Automate date formatting

Tags: r, datetime

Data contains a column "date range" that contains 2 months i.e. Oct 31,2019-Nov 30,2019 (November) and Dec 1,2019-Dec 31, 2019(December). Need to separate them in different columns under Post Period (December) and Pre Period (October) wrt to column "Revenue". I want to automate this process when I upload a file comparing any 2 months. Earlier month under "Pre Period" and later under "Post Period". Attached an example excel screenshot of the raw data and the processed data.

```
x<-data.frame("A"=c("book","mobile","tablet","desktop"),
              "B"=c("new york","chicago","london","paris"),
              "Date.Range"=c("Oct 31,2019-Nov 30,2019","Oct 31,2019-Nov 30,2019","Dec 1,2019-Dec 31, 2019","Dec 1,2019-Dec 31, 2019"),
              "Revenue"=c(542,837,1234,846))
dput(x)


structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("book", 
"desktop", "mobile", "tablet"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("chicago", "london", "new york", "paris"
), class = "factor"), Date.Range = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Dec 1,2019-Dec 31, 2019", "Oct 31,2019-Nov 30,2019"
), class = "factor"), Revenue = c(542, 837, 1234, 846)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

**Raw Data.**
[image: Raw Data]

**Processed Data.**
[image: Processed Data]

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R's `reshape` function:

```
df = reshape(data = x,idvar = c("A","B"),direction = "wide",timevar  = "DateRange")
colnames(df)=c("A","B","pre","post")
```

Comment: This splits the date but the values from "Revenue" column are not integrated in the new columns

Answer (score 1):

We can extract one date from `Date.Range`, `arrange` the data according to it, create a new `period` column and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(sub("-.*", "", Date.Range))) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(period = rep(c("pre", "post"), each = 2)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = period, values_from = Revenue, 
                     values_fill = list(Revenue = 0)) %>%
  select(-date)


# A tibble: 4 x 5
#   A       B        Date.Range                pre  post
#  <fct>   <fct>    <fct>                   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 book    new york Oct 31,2019-Nov 30,2019   542     0
#2 mobile  chicago  Oct 31,2019-Nov 30,2019   837     0
#3 tablet  london   Dec 1,2019-Dec 31, 2019     0  1234
#4 desktop paris    Dec 1,2019-Dec 31, 2019     0   846
```